# upgrade from selenium rc to webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

hi iam using selenium rc 1.0.3 (java client). If i want to upgrade to
WebDriver, will there be backward compatibility? Will it be like simply
using webdriver jar  and methods will be same? Or, Will it be like
writing from scrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `WebDriverBackedSelenium` to create a selenium impelementation

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, URL);
selenium.open()
selenium.type() or any other function;
```

This way your existing selenium functions need not be written and new functions can use `driver`.

The following info is available at this [link](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html)

**Pros**

Allows for the WebDriver and Selenium APIs to live side-by-side

Provides a simple mechanism for a managed migration from the Selenium RC API to WebDriver’s

Does not require the standalone Selenium RC server to be run

**Cons**

Does not implement every method

More advanced Selenium usage (using “browserbot” or other built-in JavaScript methods from 
Selenium Core) may not work

Some methods may be slower due to underlying implementation differences

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience it was worthwhile to move from Selenium RC to WebDriver. While moving to WebDriver I also refactored my automation framework to make it more user friendly, robust, maintainable and scalable. The kind of tools, strategies and patterns I used are explained in detail at [Web GUI automation tools strategies patterns](http://xebee.xebia.in/2012/03/30/web-gui-automation-tools-strategies-patterns/)

Comment: You can visit for details:  http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_migrating_from_rc_to_webdriver.html